# How to call multiple buttons together in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button

I'm trying to create a window with 3 buttons. When a user clicks on one of the buttons, the assigned function is called. Here is my code, I tried everything from what I read in the documentation, but I can't seem to get over it!

I also added the functions called by the program, they work perfectly, just adding them for reference. Also, the buttons() function is called only one time and it's a simple call without argument.

```
def buttons():
    root.geometry('1000x1000')

    btncreation = tkinter.Button(root, text='Order by Creation',
                                 command=creation)
    btncreation.pack()

    btnmodified = tkinter.Button(root, text='Order by Last Modified',
                                 command=lastmodified)
    btnmodified.pack()

    btnaccessed = tkinter.Button(root, text='Order by Last Accessed',
                                 command=lastaccessed)
    btnaccessed.pack()


def creation():
    lst.sort(key=os.path.getctime)
    num = 1
    for line in lst:
        dst = newpath + name + str(num) + suffix
        rename(line, dst)
        num += 1


def lastmodified():
    lst.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
    num = 1
    for line in lst:
        dst = newpath + name + str(num) + suffix
        rename(line, dst)
        num += 1
```

Functions called by buttons:

```
def lastaccessed():
    lst.sort(key=os.path.getatime)
    num = 1
    for line in lst:
        dst = newpath + name + str(num) + suffix
        rename(line, dst)
        num += 1
```

Also, please, please, refrain from formatting answers on my question. I just want some honest to god help and not 5 comments on how to "better format my question". If you need more info, I'll be glad to give it. But I'm not answering salty comments on the formatting :)

```
import os
import tkinter.filedialog
import pathlib
from os import rename
from tkinter import simpledialog
import getpass
import tkinter as tk

root = tkinter.Tk()

# File types list
ftypes = [
    ('Python code files', '*.py'),
    ('Perl code files', '*.pl;*.pm'),
    ('Java code files', '*.java'),
    ('C++ code files', '*.cpp;*.h'),
    ('Text files on mac', '*.rtf'),
    ('Text files', '*.txt'),
    ("PDF files", "*.pdf"),
    ('All files', '*'),
]


# The function renames and relocates selected files depending on the sorting selected
def creation():
    lst.sort(key=os.path.getctime)
    num = 1
    for line in lst:
        dst = newpath + name + str(num) + suffix
        rename(line, dst)
        num += 1


def lastmodified():
    lst.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
    num = 1
    for line in lst:
        dst = newpath + name + str(num) + suffix
        rename(line, dst)
        num += 1


def lastaccessed():
    lst.sort(key=os.path.getatime)
    num = 1
    for line in lst:
        dst = newpath + name + str(num) + suffix
        rename(line, dst)
        num += 1


def hide(root):
    root.withdraw()


def show(root):
    root.update()
    root.deiconify()


def buttons():
    root.geometry('1000x1000')

    btncreation = tkinter.Button(root, text='Order by Creation',
                                 command=creation)
    btncreation.pack()

    btnmodified = tkinter.Button(root, text='Order by Last Modified',
                                 command=lastmodified)
    btnmodified.pack()

    btnaccessed = tkinter.Button(root, text='Order by Last Accessed',
                                 command=lastaccessed)
    btnaccessed.pack()




hide(root)

# Window to select files to order
filez = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames(title='Select files to rename (must be all of the same type!)')

# List populated with file names
lst = list(filez)

# Saves the extension of the selected files
suffix = pathlib.Path(lst[0]).suffix

# Window to get user input on file naming

# Asks user for file names, while loop won't break if no name is given
USER_INP = simpledialog.askstring(title="File Names",
                                  prompt="Name your files:")

while USER_INP == '':
    USER_INP = simpledialog.askstring(title="File Names",
                                      prompt="Name your files:")

# Gets username for path use
username = getpass.getuser()

name = USER_INP

# Asks user for folder name, while loop won't break if no name is given
USER_INP2 = simpledialog.askstring(title="Folder Name",
                                   prompt="Name your folder:")

while USER_INP2 == '':
    USER_INP2 = simpledialog.askstring(title="Folder Name",
                                       prompt="Name your folder:")

foldername = USER_INP2

# Creates new folder for ordered files, if folder exists, it uses it
newpath = r'/Users/' + username + '/Desktop/' + foldername + '/'
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)

buttons()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If formatting is not correct, the code will be unreadable. Fixing the formatting is just as vital as giving more information.

Comment: You still have not asked your question nor told us the problem you are facing.

Comment: @Cool Cloud the problem is that the buttons won’t appear for some reason. Even the window.

Comment: Have you forgot to use `root.mainloop()`?

Comment: @Cool Cloud , no, it’s just at the end of all the code.

Comment: Maybe you need to give more code. So far seems fine to me.

Comment: @CoolCloud I just added all the code at the end of the question.

Comment: Is it not clear, that the window is hidden because you hid it purposely with `hide(root)`.

Comment: I used hide(root) to hide all the root windows, but they do need to be hidden as they are blank. I don't think they hide the buttons. Anyways I'll try now and answer in a minute.

Comment: @CoolCloud it was that, my wrong. But how can I hide those bad looking and blank extra windows I get?

Comment: Also, how do I get the buttons to work. If I click them, they won't send the command and they won't disappear...

Comment: Looks like you have got a new question, make a new post for a new question please. It just bloats this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start by using `hide(root)` but before or after calling `buttons()` say, `show(root)`, so:

```
# Rest of your code
hide(root)
# Rest of your code

show(root)
buttons()
```

Comment: This won't actually work, buttons are not showing...

Comment: I tried the code right now, it creates a changes the window size and the code works for me.

Comment: I did just as you said, hide(root) before the code, then show(root) before the buttons() function. Gonna eat lunch, I'll try to answer as soon as possibile. Thanks for the kind help and hear from you in some time :)

Comment: @MichelangeloAmorusoManzari Take a look at the window I got.

Comment: @MichelangeloAmorusoManzari Added.

Comment: I have the same code, not working for some reason :(

Comment: First it will pop up a dialog window, after choosing file, it will show 2 pop up windows with entry boxes after that it will pop up the big window, right? Make sure you dont trigger any errors in between.

Comment: yeah I have no errors in between. Same code as your, for some reason it's not working. I restarted everything an still nothing... Sorry for the late answer, I was easting lunch :) I even tried copying your code, nothing changed.

Comment: I solved it! In your code I don't know why it ran, maybe your IDE modified it during execution. In the show function, the second row should be root.iconify(), not root.deinconify(). Now I just need to make the buttons work :/

Comment: `root.deiconify` is used to show up a window hidden with `root.withdraw`.